# How to make external events box dynamically extended and hollow circles aligned

Tags: css, html, fullcalendar, html-lists

This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
<pre>
         CONTAINER External Events Box Shrink or Enlarge
<-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
|                      Text LEFT(ED) internal CONTAINER                                      |
|    --------------    --------------------------------------------------   --------------   |
|   | Info li       | |Content li                                        | | Info li       | |
|   | wrapped into  | |shrink or enlarge to contents  OR                 | | wrapped into  | |
|   | hollow circle1| |max size: (External  container width - 2X(info li)| | hollow circle2| |
|    --------------   |---------------------------------------------------  ---------------  |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</pre>
```

1- Hollow circles on the right side sould be all aligned (See picture)

2- Hollow circles on the left side  sould be all aligned (See picture)

3- Extend(Enlarge or Schrink) dynamically the external 
   events box to wrap externally the hollow circles(One on the left + the 
   second on the right + Text container(holding the description name lines).

N.B:

- If the first name line in bold reach the red Line
  (see the following picture) it must not continue 
  on a second line( means the first line should be 
  always an inline bold block) and hence push 
  forward to extend the gray container.
- If the second line written in smaller caracters reach the red Line
  (see the following picture) it must break down into a thirth line fourth and 
  so on until it complets.
- (each tuple(hollowCircle1,nameLines,hollowCircle2) is enclosed in its own 
  wrapper ul.

  [image]

  ```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id='external-events'>
    <h4 >Draggable books</h4>

       <li style="display: inline;margin: 0;padding: 0;border: none;list-style-type: none;" ng-repeat="book in books track by $index"  
               id="book.id">
            <ul style="margin: 0;padding: 0;border: none;list-style-type: none; display: flex;"  class="fc-event" data-drag="true"  data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" jqyoui-draggable="{index {{$index}},placeholder:true,animate:true}">

              <li style="margin: 0;padding: 0;border: none;list-style-type: none; display: inline;" class="circle" >
              0</li><br><br><br><br>
              <li style="margin: 0;padding: 0;border: none;list-style-type: none; display: inline;" ng-bind-html="book.content['name']"</li>
              <li style="margin: 0;padding: 0;border: none;list-style-type: none; display: inline;" class="circle" >
              2/10<br></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
  <div id='calendar-container'>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </div>
  </body>
  ```

### CSS

```
   ul {
        list-style-type: none;}
    ul.columns>li {
         display: inline-block;
         padding-right: 0cm;
         margin-left: 0px;
    }
    ul.columns>li:before {
        content:"";
        display: list-item;
        position: absolute;
   }
   h4 {
       color: white;
       display: inline; 
       border-bottom: 3px solid darken($fendersblue, 10);
       padding-bottom: 8px;
       line-height: 1.75em;
  }
  .fancy3 {
         background-color: darken($fendersblue, 5);
  }
  #calendar
  {
           padding: 0 10px;
           width: 650px;
          float: right;
          margin: 0px 0px 10px 55px;
  }
  #external-events {
      width: 500px;
      padding: 0 0px;
      border: 0px solid #ccc;/* gray moyen*/
      background: #eee;/* #5D6D7E;(Blue mat) */ /* #eee color gray*/
     text-align: left;
}

    #external-events h4 {
      font-size: 30px;
      margin-top: 0;
      padding-top: 1em;
      color:gray;
   }

   #external-events .fc-event {
       cursor: pointer;
       position:relative; 
       z-index: 100;
       background: #eee;
   }
   #external-events p {
       margin: 0 18em 0 0;
       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: bold;
       color: gray; /* color gray */
  }
  .circle {
       position: relative;
       display: inline-block;
       width: 10%;
       height: 25%;
       padding: 0 0px;
       border-radius: 360px;
       /* Just making it pretty */
       @shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
       @shadow-length: 4px;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 @shadow-length 0 0 @shadow;
       box-shadow: 0 @shadow-length 0 0 @shadow;
       text-shadow: 0 @shadow-length 0 @shadow;
       background: #FFFFFF;/*color white*/
       color: #f05907;/* color red*/
       font-family: Helvetica, Arial Black, sans;
       font-size: 10;
       text-align: center;
   }
   p span 
  {
     display: block;
  }
  p:first-line {
     color: gray;
     font-size: 25px;
     font-weight: bold italic;
  }
  p {
      white-space: pre
  }
```

Css is included in [my CodePen](https://codepen.io/adier/pen/ebarXd?editors=1111)
 Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of your CodePen was a bit of a mess of invalid HTML, illogical use of markup, conflicting styles and seemingly arbitrary (and confusing) mixture of inline styles and CSS definitions.

There was too much to go into specifics. However, here is a version which gets you much closer to the layout you envisaged, I hope:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div id='external-events'>
  <h4 >Draggable books</h4>

          <ul data-drag="true"  data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" jqyoui-draggable="{index {{$index}},placeholder:true,animate:true}">
            <li class="fc-event" ng-repeat="book in books track by $index"  
             id="book.id">
        <div class="circle">0</div>
        <div class="left content" ng-bind-html="book.content['name']"></div>
            <div class="left rating">2/10</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
<div id='calendar-container'>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul>li {
  display:block;
    padding-right: 0cm;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

h4 {
  color: gray;
  display: inline; 
  border-bottom: 3px solid darken($fendersblue, 10);
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  font-size:600;
}

#calendar{
 padding: 0 10px;
 width: 650px;
 float: right;
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 55px;
}

#external-events {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 0 0px;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;/* gray moyen*/
  background: #eee;/* #5D6D7E;(Blue mat) */ /* #eee color gray*/
  text-align: left;
}

#external-events .fc-event {

  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #eee;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

.content span
{
  color: gray;
}
.fc-event span:first-child
{
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold italic;
}

.fc-event div
{
  padding:3px;
  margin-right:5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content
{
  float:left;
  max-width:75%;
}

.clear
{
  clear:both;
}

.circle {
  float:left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 25%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 360px;


  /* Just making it pretty */
  @shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  @shadow-length: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 @shadow-length 0 0 @shadow;
          box-shadow: 0 @shadow-length 0 0 @shadow;
  text-shadow: 0 @shadow-length 0 @shadow;
  background: #FFFFFF;/*color white*/
  color: #f05907;/* color red*/
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial Black, sans;
  font-size: 10;
  text-align: center;
}

.rating
{
  float:right;
  background: #FFFFFF;/*color white*/
  color: #f05907;/* color red*/
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial Black, sans;
  font-size: 10;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 360px;
}
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce){

  $scope.books = [

            {
                id: 'id1',
                content: {
                    name: '<span>Alain du sceau france</span><br><span> Canada Madagascar philipine</span>',
                    price: 'price1',
                    date: 'd1'
                }
            },
            {
                id: 'id2',
                content: {
                    name: '<span>Name zu Long zu Schreiben Bis Here ist Ein Beispiel</span><br><span>Maneschester Canada Madagascar philipine</span>',
                    price: 'price2',
                    date: 'd2'
                }
            },
            {
                id: 'id3',
                content: {
                    name: '<span>name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                    price: 'price3',
                    date: 'd3'
                }
            }
        ];
  $scope.books.forEach(function(book) {
    book.content.name = $sce.trustAsHtml(book.content.name);
  })

  // initialize the external events
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------

  $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    $(this).data('event', {
      title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
      stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
    });

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
      zIndex: 999,
      revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
      revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
    });

  });

  // initialize the calendar
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
    drop: function() {
      // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
      if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
        $(this).remove();
      }
    },
    eventDragStop: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {

                      if(isEventOverDiv(jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY)) {


                          //////////
                          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                 var el = $( "<div class='fc-event'>" ).appendTo('#external-        events').text(event.id);

    }
            }            
  });
var isEventOverDiv = function(x, y) {

                    var external_events = $( '#external-events' );
                    var offset = external_events.offset();
                    offset.right = external_events.width() + offset.left;
                    offset.bottom = external_events.height() + offset.top;

                    // Compare
                    if (x >= offset.left
                        && y >= offset.top
                        && x <= offset.right
                        && y <= offset .bottom) { return true; }
                    return false;

                }

}]);
```

CodePen demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JwQOMQ?editors=1111